# Disable a Button for 90 sec when pressed in swift

Tags: button, time, nstimer

I have button that show up a modal view but i want that if the user click it he wont be able to use it again for 90 seconds. how can i do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the IBAction of the button disable the button and set a timer like this:

```
self.button.enabled = false
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(90, target: self, selector: "enableButton", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

And create the func called when the timer ends counting:

```
func enableButton() {
    self.button.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 4

```
sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 90, repeats: false, block: { _ in
    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**#Swift 3**

Write this code where you want to disable button.

```
self.buttonTest.isEnabled = false
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 90, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.enableButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Here buttonTest is the Outlet of that button.

And Write this code anywhere inside of your ViewController

```
 func enableButton() {
        self.buttonTest.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Let me know for any clarification. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

I wanted this answer to be much generic so developers find it more helpful

first , is the button hooked as an Outlet or as an action ?
in both cases you will need to connect it as an outlet

second, I recommend you using a closure instead of writing a func then calling it  you can simply do the following

```
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonWithTimer: UIButton!{
    didSet{
        self.buttonWithTimer.isEnabled = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 90, repeats: false) {  
             [weak self]timer in
            self?.buttonWithTimer.isEnabled = true
        } // [weak self]inside the closure is to break a possible    
          // memory sicle  
    }
}
```